# Proving that 2 statements are equivalent while using Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying some number theory from notes and I am unable to deduce following result.

> Chebyshev's Theorem : There exists constants c<1<C such that $cx /\log x \leq \pi(x) \leq Cx/\log x$.

It is written that Chebyshev's estimate is equivalent to $c' x \leq \psi(x) \leq C' x$ .

I thought of using the result that lim x tending to $\infty$ $\frac{\psi(x) }{x} =  $ lim x tending to $\infty$ $\frac{\pi(x) log x}{x}$.

But this proves the result for only when x tends to $\infty$ ,

> How can I prove equivalence for any x? Can you please tell.

Comment: do u know summation by parts?

Comment: This is usually done by summation by parts. To get more explicit bounds, see for instance Theorem 4.6 of Apostol's text.

Comment: @mathworker21 yes